# how to turn this to into a tree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was doing a challenge of building a tree from all html elements. And I am 90% done, but I got stuck...

How do I change this string into a tree?:

> mystring= "red1/(none)-red2/red1-blue1/red2-blue2/red2-blue3/red2-red3/red1-red4/red3-red5/red4-red6/red5-blue4/red6";

**After splitting them by "-" we will have:**

10 groups of -> (parameter1)/(parameter2)

The first parameter it is the object,
The second parameter is the 'in-what-it-will-be-contained'

I have no idea how to move every 'parameter1' inside 'parameter2'. (note: sometimes the parameter1 will be the parameter2 of a parameter1)

**Visual example of what I mean with a parameter is inside another parameter: (this example uses exactly the string above)**

[image: http://img853.imageshack.us/img853/6893/grg.jpg]

Probably we should use arrays?, idk... I am totally lost :sadface:

Comment: Is turning into tree a challenge?

Comment: so, what have you accomplished so far? Let us know so we can help, this is no **Code Generator Forum**!

Comment: I'm trying to understand how asking us to do it is a personal challenge for you.  So I won't do it for you but here is a hint - use recursion + one of the parameters to the function is stack.

Comment: "how asking us to do it is a personal challenge", i did the hard part that was getting that string. That string is just an example, but It was generated by a crazy code that I entirely created (the challenge).

Comment: wow is that the new way to get your question answered.. im wondering if SO should introduce a new tab in its main page titled Challenge. it will be by people with absolutely no prior history on SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I found a simpler/shorter/neater way using the JQuery function [AppendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)

**We just need to:**

1. Split the parameters...
2. Create one *div* for each (parameter1)
3. Use a loop to move every (parameter1) inside (parameter2) using the
   AWESOME [AppendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) function that JQuery offers

The best thing is that they are actually inside them, so you can easily put a Hide/Show effect to make a cool effect

Comment: This is a slick technique for getting the HTML so long as you don't care about having a corresponding object representation.  The technique is equally valid for pure JavaScript: `$(childEl).appendTo(parentEl)` is the equivalent of `parentEl.appendChild(childEl)`.  An awesome method, yes, but available in IE4, and *when used with a single element reference*, jQuery's wrapper is hardly different from the native method - both return a reference to the child element.  But, if you're already using jQuery, `.appendTo()` obviously makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a little more concise and straight forward.  It uses an object as a dictionary to lookup the parent, rather than a function that has to recursively iterate the tree to find the parent.  That recursive function is expensive.  An object lookup is quick.

First, for convenience, I'd define an object type:

```
function TreeNode(name) {
    this.Name = name;
    this.Children = [];
}
```

Then I'd add a method to do the work.  This parses your tree string:

```
TreeNode.ParseTree = function (treeString) {
    var root = new TreeNode("");
    var nodes = {};
    var pairs = treeString.split("-");
    pairs.forEach(function(pair) {
        var parts = pair.split("/");
        var parentName = parts[1];
        var childName = parts[0];
        var node;
        if (parentName == "(none)") {
            node = root;
            root.Name = childName;
        }
        else {
            node = new TreeNode(childName);
            nodes[parentName].Children.push(node);
        }
        nodes[childName] = node;
    });
    return root;
};
```

That's it!  Now, to get visual representations of your tree, you can add some prototype methods to `TreeNode`.  First, override `.toString()`:

```
TreeNode.prototype.toString = function(indent) {
    indent = indent || "";
    var strings = [indent + this.Name];
    this.Children.forEach(function(child) {
        strings.push(child.toString(indent + "    "));
    });
    return strings.join("\n");
};
```

Then, add a `.Render()` method to display the tree within a web page:

```
TreeNode.prototype.Render = function(container) {
    var nodeEl = container.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
    nodeEl.className = "treeNode";
    var nameEl = nodeEl.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
    nameEl.className = "treeNodeName";
    nameEl.appendChild(document.createTextNode(this.Name));
    var childrenEl = nodeEl.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
    childrenEl.className = "treeNodeChildren";
    this.Children.forEach(function(child) {
        child.Render(childrenEl);
    });
    return nodeEl;
};
```

Here it is in action: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/wwFBx/

**Edit:** I didn't notice the jQuery tag in your post, here's a render method that's all jQuery, and produces simpler HTML which you seem to imply is what you want:

```
TreeNode.prototype.Render = function(container) {
    var el = $("<div>").appendTo(container).text(this.Name);
    $.each(this.Children, function() {
        this.Render(el);
    });
    return el;
};
```

This JSFiddle uses jQuery, even replacing `Array.forEach` with `$.each`:  http://jsfiddle.net/wwFBx/1/

As an alternative, you might consider just serializing your tree as JSON.  Eg:

```
"{\"Name\":\"red1\",\"Children\":[{\"Name\":\"red2\",\"Children\":[{\"Name\":\"blue1\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Name\":\"blue2\",\"Children\":[]},{\"Name\":\"blue3\",\"Children\":[]}]},{\"Name\":\"red3\",\"Children\":[{\"Name\":\"red4\",\"Children\":[{\"Name\":\"red5\",\"Children\":[{\"Name\":\"red6\",\"Children\":[{\"Name\":\"blue4\",\"Children\":[]}]}]}]}]}]}"
```

or maybe:

```
"{\"red1\":{\"red2\":{\"blue1\":{},\"blue2\":{},\"blue3\":{}},\"red4\":{\"red5\":{\"red6\":{\"blue4\":{}}}}}}"
```

Parse the string via `JSON.parse()`.

**Disclaimer:** I've referenced `Array.forEach()` and `JSON.parse()` which are built-in to modern browsers but are not supported by older browsers.  To enable these functions in older browsers, see this [documentation on `Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/array/foreach#Compatibility) and this [shim for `JSON.parse()`](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js).

Comment: works awesomely! (the previous code by 'minitech' was also good, but the order of the list changed from first-last to last-first, although that can be fixed, your code looks easier and neater) Thank you :)

Comment: @ogps2: Wait, this was for turning into HTML? You can use the *built-in* node structures to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's about how I would do it, using an array of "unplaced" elements and looping through it until they're all placed:

```
var str = "red1/(none)-red2/red1-blue1/red2-blue2/red2-blue3/red2-red3/red1-red4/red3-red5/red4-red6/red5-blue4/red6";
var unplaced = [];
var tree = null;
var elements = str.split(/[\/\-]/);

function findNodeByName(nodeName, context) {
    if(context.name === nodeName) return context;

    for(var i = 0; i < context.children.length; i++) {
        var subSearch = findNodeByName(nodeName, context.children[i]);
        if(subSearch) return subSearch;
    }

    return null;
}

var element, node, parent, thisElement, i;

for(i = 0; node = elements[i]; i += 2) {
    node = elements[i];
    parent = elements[i + 1];
    thisElement = {name: node, children: []};

    if(!tree && parent === '(none)') {
        tree = thisElement;
    } else if(tree) {
        var parentNode = findNodeByName(parent, tree);
        if(parentNode) {
            parentNode.children.push(thisElement);
        } else {
            unplaced.push(thisElement);
        }
    }
}

var oldLength;

while(unplaced.length) {
    oldLength = unplaced.length;

    for(i = 0; element = unplaced[i]; i++) {
        var parentNode = findNodeByName(parent, tree);
        if(parentNode) {
            parentNode.children.push(element);
            unplaced.splice(i, 1);
            i--;
        }
    }

    if(oldLength === unplaced.length) {
        throw new SyntaxError("The string is not a valid tree.");
    }
}

// The result is contained in "tree".
```

You can see the result at: http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/tJSpN/

One with a function: http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/tJSpN/1/

And one with more error-checking: http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/tJSpN/2/

Comment: how do i call the "tree"? alert(tree); or document.write(tree); are not working

Comment: @ogps92: Sorry, see the new jsFiddles at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to create tree nodes of the form :

```
node = {
str:"red1",
subBranches : new Array()
}
```

Once you have that, you may add the sub-branches iterating through the array, adding such nodes for each found correct couple, and removing the couples already placed in `rootNode.subBranches`. Then you recursively do the same for every sub-branche.

Comment: the main root is the one that have "red1/(none)". Also every "blue" is always empty.